# Viber Ubuntu 14.04 second launch problem

Tags: viber

I've installed Viber with .deb file from viber site. Than i've started it and entered the code. Everything was fine, viber was working well. But then i've switched it off and tried to turn on again. And nothing happened at all. There was no viber in processes, and there was no error message. Viber in the second time just silently didn't start. Do anybody know the way to fix it?

Thank, u)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem on Ubuntu 16.04 but I guess there's no difference. I found solution on Viber support web site https://support.viber.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1506350-opening-ports-for-viber-desktop#.V_1UOrX9-Ak

I had to open following ports for both TCP and UDP: 5242, 4244, 5243, 80, 443. After that everything working fine